# How to execute custom sql query in elfinder file manager

Tags: php, web, file-manager

I am using elfinder file manager in one of my project. I am developing my project in PHP. I am new with using this file manager.

Now, I want to execute an SQL query when file will be uploaded and want to put track of each file uploaded with each user separately. So I am not getting that how to customize this thing.

For Example, I am a user and I have registered. Each user has their separate account and they can upload their files there in his/her account.

Now, suppose I am user and uploading 1 image in my account. So when I am uploading my file. I want to insert that file name, size and all other details with user_id in my database table. So I can manage track of each user uploaded files.

Please any one can help me here for this?

Thanks in ADVANCE

Comment: read this : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I am not asking that how to upload file but asking how to customize elfinder with my requirement

Comment: I dont know what is `elfinder` at all

Comment: please see this http://elfinder.org/ for your reference

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I know elfinder admitts callbacks, but I can´t find a  propoer documentation to save to database every action (upload file, delete file, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you want to know how to store uploaded files data in database then You must read php manual about [file upload feature](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

on other hand you just need to explore [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array as it contains all details of Uploaded file